# Change background when using functions

Tags: lua, notepad++

How to change the background when using functions to have more visibility ?

Comment: I'm sorry you're going to have to elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu settings > syntaxic color, choose the language (I think it lua for you) then select `INSTRUCTION WORD` and then choose the color you want for the background.